# How to generate message boxes to display during and at the conclusion of a batch file process

Tags: batch-processing

I have created a batch file that generates a file listing output to a text file and then displays that text file in a browser. Since the listing takes awhile to generate, I want a message box to display during processing (and ideally another message box to display at the end indicating that the process completed) before it displays to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Place a line at the beginning of your script and at the end of your script.

'echo "Entry"'
'echo "Exit"'

Have the output sent to a log file which updates. This will be different depending on your language, but fairly easy to do.

As a separate process make an if statement that greps for Enrty and Exit. In Bash it would be:

```
grep_output=`grep Entry <file>`
if [ "$grep_output" == "" ]; then
    entryoutput=true;
else
    entryoutput=false;
fi

grep_output=`grep Exit <file>`
if [ "$grep_output" == "" ]; then
    exitoutput=true;
else
    exitoutput=false;
fi

while :; do
    if $entryoutput=true and exitoutput=false; then
    sleep 10
done
```

Not 100% on the syntax of that two condition if statement above.